# How to stop fstream from consuming character escapes?

Tags: c++, escaping, fstream

I'm editing a file, and appending to it. I have a `"` in there somewhere I'm trying to preserve the escape character for. As this code writes other code, which then gets compiled.

```
#define EDIT_FILE fstream::out | fstream::binary | fstream::in | fstream::ate
#define REWRITE_FILE fstream::out | fstream::binary | fstream::in | fstream::trunc

fstream *fileStream  = new fstream("path/to/file", REWRITE_FILE);
//  add some text to file. Then open again for edits.
fileStream->close();
fileStream->open("path/to/file", EDIT_FILE);
*filestream << "\\\\\"";
```

I've tried changing the amount of slashes with no luck. I tried removing `fstream::out`, which other answers suggested should work, and that just caused the program to crash when trying to write to the file. Which combination of flags should I be using for appending to the end of the file, while preserving escape characters?

Comment: What does "consuming character escapes" mean?

Comment: A bit strange to have an `fstream*` pointer instead of the object. I suppose in your actual code you're initializing an actual `fstream` object somewhere.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mean it doesn't leave the `\`. The slash is consumed and the escaped character is printed to the file.  I need both as I'm writing a file to compile.

Comment: There's nothing in `std::fstream` that does this, this has nothing to do with `std::fstream`. This is C and C++ syntax for string literals. `std::string s="foo\\bar";`. You will be surprised to learn that `s` will have a single backslash character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in need of something like [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)?

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::fstream file("test.txt", std::ios::out);
    if(file) {
        file<<R"f(\\\\\")f";
    }
}
```

And then [yields](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94bcd31d9b62d9ee)

```
\\\\\"
```

Raw string literals can be created using the syntax `R"delimiter(raw_characters)delimiter"`. In the above case, `f` serves as the delimiter. They are specifically to avoid escaping of characters. One care that needs to be taken is that the delimiter shouldn't appear in the raw characters.

EDIT:

As requested, one way to go the binary route would be to just directly write in the ASCII values of the characters, obviating the need to escape them, as follows (no error checking!):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

namespace {
    char BACK_SLASH = 92; //ASCII for '\'
    char QUOTE = 34; //ASCII for '"'
}

int main() {
    std::fstream file("test.bin", std::ios::binary|std::ios::out);
    if(file) {
        std::vector<char> str(10, BACK_SLASH);
        str.push_back(QUOTE);
        file.write(str.data(), str.size());
        file.put('\n');
    }
}
```

which [yields](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4183d6f15e873d46)

```
\\\\\\\\\\"
```

This is probably one of the ways I can think of if one wants to avoid escaping the characters but well...it's ugly.

Comment: That's definitely helpful. I thought I should be able to edit the file in `binary` mode to get similar behavior?

Comment: @ZeroPhase I've edited my answer to include one possible way to do it via binary if you absolutely want to avoid escaping.